# Website being indexed twice by Google

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, wordpress, google-index

Website is being indexed by Google twice.

Both indexes have the right SEO information for the home page, such as title and description. However for the sublinks there are two versions, one version of the indexed site that has the correct sublinks and sublink information, and the other version that has all sublinks pointing to the home page with the format of these wrong sublinks being `http://example.com/#random%20text`

I have gone into webmasters and chosen my prefered domain, I have tried removing these wrong sublink pages, but due to redirecting to home, it stops home from being indexed, so I reverted this change, I have tried demoting the sublinks, it did not work, I've tried adding `<meta name="fragment" content="!">` to my header, it did not work, I have tried disabling all plugins on WordPress to see if that was the reason, it was not.

I've everything I can think of and would really appreciate some help as to how I can stop Google indexing one version of my website with all the wrong sublinks.

If it's of any help, when I search for the business website name on Google as "businessexample" it shows the broken link index version, and when I search as "business example" it shows the correct version.

Comment: What is the format of the correct "sublink"?

Comment: example.com/sub-page/